# Open clicked li's child div

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, toggle

I am using angular 6 application where i am listing a few elements,

**Html:**

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li *ngFor="let item of items">
        {{item.order}}
        <button (click)="openCurrentOrder()"> open {{item.id}} </button> <br>
        <div class="list-items inner-list-items" *ngIf="isActive">
            opened order {{item.id}}
        </div>
    <br><br><br>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  items: any = [
    {id: "1",order: "one"},
    {id: "2",order: "two"},
    {id: "3",order: "three"},
    {id: "4",order: "four"},
    {id: "5",order: "five"},
  ]

  isActive: boolean = false;

  openCurrentOrder() {
    console.log("opened");
    this.isActive = true;
  }

}
```

Here if i click on particular order button the respective child div needs to gets opened.

For eg, here the list as follows,

Order 1 button
Order 2 button
.
.
Order 5 button

When i click the order 2 button, then a text with `opened order 2` will be displayed and all other order;s child div needs to be in hidden.. This is the expected result..

But now when i click over particular button, all the child divs getting opened.

How to open only the particular div's child on button click?

KIndly help me to achieve the result using only pure javascript or typescript **without query**.

Working **stackblitz** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-llhfhp

Comment: You only have 1 `isActive` variable, so when you set it to `true`, it is `true` for every element. Instead, you should have an `isActive` property on your array items instead, and do `this.items[1].isActive = true` for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your stackblitz here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/open-current-div
Indeed, you have to add current item as parameter of `openCurrentOrder` function. Besides, add a field in buttons to know if current button is opened or not.
You need to have one variable `isActive` for each button. If not, all buttons have the same `*ngIf` and the same condition.

Comment: Why you have deleted your stackblitz??

Comment: Soory I changed the name yesterday : https://stackblitz.com/edit/open-current-div

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to add to the "items" object the isActive: false. This way the loop is not on all the buttons, only on one id. 
See my code if it helps you:

**HTML**:

```
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li *ngFor="let item of items">
        {{item.order}}
        <button (click)="openCurrentOrder(item.id)"> open {{item.id}} </button> <br>
        <div class="list-items inner-list-items" *ngIf="item.isActive">
            opened order {{item.id}}
        </div>
    <br><br><br>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**TS:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  items: any = [
    {id: "1",order: "one", isActive: false},
    {id: "2",order: "two", isActive: false},
    {id: "3",order: "three", isActive: false},
    {id: "4",order: "four", isActive: false},
    {id: "5",order: "five", isActive: false},
  ]



  openCurrentOrder(e) {
    console.log("opened");
    this.items[e -1].isActive = true;

  }

}
```